# How to get rid of \n in python output

Tags: python

Input:

```
question1 = content[0],"\n",content[1]
print(question_order[0])
```

Output:

```
('How secret should you keep your passwords? \n', '\n', 'A)Never give out passwords except to your parents B)Give them only to your best friends C)Give them to strangers \n')
```

Comment: What relevance does question order have?

Comment: So what exactly is `question_order` here? Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: its part of a bigger code with a randomized sequence

Comment: That doesn't answer our questions, however.

Comment: You: "How do I tie my shoelaces?" Them: "Depends. Are we talking about running shoes or marching boots or flip-flops, or what?" You: "The building has three floors. The rains come early this year."

Comment: should i upload the whole code

Comment: Typically, never upload the whole code but keep this in mind. If the code is too long, people zone out and don't actually read it.

If you fail to provide useful information, like why, and with what (Python2 vs. Python3), people cannot answer your question. The XY problem is a great thing to remember: why are you executing this code and not solely what.
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too vague.
If `content` is not an externel reference, and is created by you, I'd suggest to strip whitespace off the values before storing them.

If stripping `content` at its definition is not possible, I suggest you form `question1` from stripped values, before appending them to `question_order` (assuming, `question_order` is a collection of the same type as `question1`).

```
question1 = content[0].strip(),"\n",content[1].strip()
print(question1)
```

will print:

```
('How secret should you keep your passwords?', '\n', 'A)Never give out passwords except to your parents B)Give them only to your best friends C)Give them to strangers')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you were vague with your question, this was the best I could do:

```
print([i.replace('\n', '') for i in question_order[0] if i.replace('\n', '') != ''])
```